# How do I limit access to a bucket in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have multiple people working in GCS in my project, and I have two buckets with backup of my databases. Now I don't want everyone to have access to my backups.
What would be the best way to limit access to a specific bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `best way` is very vague. Google Cloud Storage offers many methods. Which method to choose depends on your understanding of Google Cloud, [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam), [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists), and encryption.

There are three different types of access that you need to manage: Read, Modify and Delete.

In your use case, protecting backups of databases, I would create a separate project, grant permissions at the Project IAM member level to [access the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) to the backup system and only required members of your team and add object-level [KMS encryption](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/kms). This method is very secure.

For buckets in the same Project ID as the members, you have two choices. IAM and ACLs. You need a solid understanding of IAM and ACLs to implement anything using these methods securely when multiple project members have access to the bucket.

If you grant IAM access to a bucket, all objects in that bucket can be accessed.

You can also control access via bucket and/or object ACLs.

You can also encrypt the database backup files using KMS and then only grant access to the KMS keys to specific individuals. Without access to the KMS keys, they cannot read the files.

To add to the above, also look into [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) and [Bucket Lock](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock) to prevent your database files from being deleted or modified. Review these methods as they affect all objects in the bucket and can increase your costs as objects are never deleted.